# Python Django filter avoid overlapping between range dates

Tags: python, django, timestamp, logic

I'm having a bit of a logic blank this morning.

I get 2 `datetime` objects from a user (a range), `start_time` and `end_time`.

Idea is to return an exists if there's an overlap between the input range and an existing schedule time.

I tried the following, but I'm far off with the logic.

```
if Schedule.objects.filter(start_date__gte=ts_start, end_date__lte=ts_start).filter(start_date__gte=ts_end, end_date__lte=ts_end ).exists():
```

Comment: Are the endpoints *inclusive* or *exclusive*?

Comment: Inclusive. 

Any form of overlapping should be triggered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ranges *[b<sub>1</sub>, e<sub>1</sub>]* and *[b<sub>2</sub>, b<sub>e</sub>]* do *not* overlap if *b<sub>1</sub>>e<sub>2</sub>*, or *e<sub>1</sub><b<sub>2</sub>*. We can negate this expression to know when two intervals overlap: *b<sub>1</sub>≤e<sub>2</sub>*, and *e<sub>1</sub>≥b<sub>2</sub>*.

This thus means that we can filter with:

```
Schedule.objects.filter(start_date__lte=ts_end, end_date__gte=ts_start)
```

Answer (score 2):

You almost had it. To find all datetime ranges that overlap you just need to filter where data lower bound is less than the search upper bound and the data upper bound is greater than the search lower bound

```
overlap = Schedule.objects.filter(
    start_date__lte=ts_end,
    end_date__gte=ts_start
)
```